# firebase cloud firestore get started Failed to load error

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do the start guide of firebase firestore, copied everything here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0. But keep getting error of [Failed to load in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJYzk.png). Anybody know what I did wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>firebase</title>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyB__YWuIm8QjQdFLvZ1qv6P5-yVkYv7I9g",
          authDomain: "fireapp-b79d6.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://fireapp-b79d6.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "fireapp-b79d6",
          storageBucket: "fireapp-b79d6.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "1050532546787"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection("users").add({
          first: "Ada",
          last: "Lovelace",
          born: 1815
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you run your codes? In case I suggest you serve your project with running firebase serve command with firebase CLI. (command Line Interface.) If you are not familiar with firebase CLI here the link to use install firebase CLI and serve the project. [firebase.google.com/docs/cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) , when you serve with firebase cli, your project will be served at : `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: I run it in chrome. It seems it doesn't work in chrome. I tested in firefox, it seems working. Thank you for reply.

Comment: It shoud works at all platforms. What's the error messages?